# convert whitespace delimited stdout of command into variable in bash

Tags: bash

e.g. if `inner.bash` is simply `echo a b c`, and `outer.bash` calls `inner.bash`, how can the results of `inner.bash` be captured in a variable for user in `outer.bash`?  It's pretty simple but I don't actually know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inner.bash:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "a b c"
```

outer.bash:

```
#! /bin/sh
x=`sh ./inner.bash`
echo "result of inner is "$x
```

So the basic thing are the backquotes `bla` gives you back the outcome of bla.

Comment: I think I knew that.  Don't know why it suddenly became complicated to me.  Whoops.

Comment: Backquotes are obsolete in bash though `:-(`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -a text < <(inner.bash)
echo "$text[1]"
```